# How to set 'ClientValidationFunction' property in <asp:CustomValidator>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to use asp:CustomValidator for a tool. The problem am facing is that on calling a function  using the property 'ClientValidationFunction', the function is getting called but even a single line of javascript is not getting executed. I placed a simple alert() inside the function. Its also not executed.

Can any one please suggest a solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a code sample please

Comment: How do you know the function is getting called then ??

Comment: Hai, Akram . Thank for the response. While debugging using fire bug the break point is set . So that it tracks to the function.

Comment: Hai, Greg,                                                                    Please find the code sample

Comment: <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustCreditDebit" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"  ClientValidationFunction="CheckCreditDebit1"
                                                             ToolTip="test" Display="Dynamic" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the CustomValidator below:

```
     <asp:CustomValidator ID="valCustmCheckDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="The date   difference should not be greater than 100 days" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="LoginUserAdd" ClientValidationFunction="CompareStartAndEndDate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

It calls the following Javascript function below:

```
   function CompareStartAndEndDate(sender,args) {

    var txtBox = document.getElementById('<%=txtBoxID.ClientID %>');

    var validation=//do your validation of txtBox.value here;

   if (!validation) {

        args.IsValid = false; //this will display your validation error msg and stops at clent side itself
    }
    else {
         args.IsValid = true;// this will allow server side run
    }
```

Hope this helps..
      }

Comment: HAi Harun, Thanks for the response.                          function CheckCreditDebit1(sender, args) {
 alert("Hai");
 }
This is the function used. A simple one. I need to implement some more login inside this. But even the alert message is not coming.

Comment: I think you should give the validation group for your customValidator as well as the triggering button.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure there are no other JavaScript errors on the page.
Also, it should work if you add either *ControlToValidate* property or the *ValidationGroup* for the validator.

Comment: No need of controlToValidate as giving validation group itself calls the clientside function. The controlToValidate property is not manadtory for custom validator as your validation logic is done in another function. It is mandatory in required field validator,regular expression validator etc.

Comment: You are right, it is not mandatory to have controlToValidate for custom field. But the custom validator does work if it has either a controlToValidate OR a ValidationGroup added. I have edited my answer to make it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that was what i meant with "not manadtory".Thanks for making it clear.